# Call PageLoad of parent page after closing modal popup

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, reload, modalpopup

I have a parent page to display the project details, and user enter part details by uploading a template in a modal pop-up.
To open the modal popup I'm calling this function

```
function importfile()
{     
    var url="SCN_UploadPart.aspx";  
    var selSCE=window.showModalDialog(url,'win','help:no;status:no;scroll:no;resize:no;dialogHeight:300px;dialogWidth:490px');

    return false;
}
```

Earlier I was using OnClinetClick method of Uplaod Button to call this method, then the project page or parent page was automatically reloading. But now I'm calling it like this.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "project", "<script language='javascript'>importfile();</script>");
```

onclick of same Upload Button.

I font why the page does not reload now. I want the page to be reloaded as I am showing the content in the parent page after uploading the parts.

Please suggest me the way to reload the Parent page on click of close in modalpopup.

Comment: can't you return the project details to be displayed on the parent page as a response of upload function ? Or simply refresh the page using javascript in the file upload callback

Answer (score 0):

U can refer below link its show the demo 
http://codedisplay.com/automaticaly-refresh-parent-window-whenever-popup-window-is-closed/

http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/Refresh-parent-page-on-closing-modal-child-windowpopup-29.php

Hope it helps u

Comment: Hi. Please can you include relevant code samples from the links you've posted as to prevent the information from being lost if those sites go down.